# jQuery.hide('fast') intermittently fails to work

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have jQuery 3.6.0, jQuery-UI 1.13 and a bunch of other plugins. All JS files are stored on the server.

9 page loads out of 10, `$('selector').hide('fast')` or some other specified speed works perfectly.

*Sometimes* though it will do nothing - the element won't hide, the closure after won't call, nothing.

When I call `hide('fast')` the *first* time (when it's not working) it will add the `overflow: hidden;` inline style to the element for some reason. If I use `show('fast')` first, and then use `hide('fast')`, it doesn't add the overflow:hidden styling.

There are no error messages in JS console so it's very frustrating trying to figure it out.

Comment: `hide()` is a regular jQuery method, it has nothing to do with jQuery-UI.

Comment: Yes thanks @Barmar I know I was just mentioning it in case someone smarter than me needed to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it was a conflict of some sort with the jQuery-validation package.

I used the following code snippet to make the page continually refresh until it broke.

```
$('#test_element').hide('fast', function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':visible')) {
        console.info('Working');        
        location.reload();
    }
});
```

On reloads where hide('fast') wasn't working, it wouldn't reload again because the closure wasn't called.

Then I removed packages until it stopped breaking, which was when I removed jQuery-validate.

After updating validate, it would happily reload without issue.